# Strange TeX syntax highlighting behaviour in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a bit of a strange problem with [La]TeX syntax highlighting in vim. vim seems to randomly switch between three different syntax highlighting styles, with little rhyme or reason. It doesn't *appear* to do this for other languages, though I haven't written anything except LaTeX (using syntax highlighting) for a while now.

So: a bit of background. This problem started becoming noticeable when I switched terminal emulators (to `urxvt`), but it also appears in `roxterm`, `konsole`, and `gnome-terminal`.

Playing around with the value of the `TERM` environment variable does appear to affect the result: changing `TERM` from the default of `rxvt-unicode-256color` to `xterm` or `linux` appears to make vim not choose the third, but the first two appear to be selected at random.

I've done some Googling, to no avail. My google-fu is perhaps weak, and I apologize if this is a common problem that I've managed to overlook . . .

For reference, what the three styles look like in a sample document:

[image: Style #1]
[image: Style #2]
[image: Style #3]

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Vim) website, for TeX files, Vim scans the file and guesses whether it is LaTeX, ConTeXt, or plain TeX based on the keywords used therein. Now this is a guess, but maybe every once in a while, while you're editing, you're adding or removing some keyword that is causing it to change its guess each time.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, manually setting `g:tex_flavor` in my `.vimrc` appears to have fixed this.